# Python similar type of string to search

Tags: string, file, search, python-3.x

I have just started learning python and I have a question. I have a text file which I opened. The file has random questions. Now my question is how can I search for any question similar to this type of question "what is your .... " and "how do you ...." and return the whole question . I am using python 3.x. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you spend some time reading about regex.  The trick would be to search for a string that includes the first words you want (the "What is your" statement) and ends with a question mark.  The following docs should give you quite a bit of clarity.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html
https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html#regex-howto

Comment: Thanks will do. Are there any good books which explain regex clearly?

Comment: I'm sure there are.  I don't know of a specific one off the top of my head.  I can say that I learned everything I needed from just playing with the snippets in the documentation I linked.